# file completion function not working on android 12?

Tags: android, shell, tasker

I wrote the script for Tasker and I needed to keep a log of actions. I usually use a text file for this. On android 12, the file is overwritten all the time with new content instead of an add-on. I checked it through shell, on different firmware - the problem is repeated, on android 12. On androids of previous versions, this was not the case. What can I do about it, am I doing something wrong? Thank you for your attention.

I'm trying just echo "some text" >> some/file.txt

Comment: How could we know if you did something wrong if we dont know what you did?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.